# viewing files in SD card image file data

Tags: sqlite, blackberry

What I did is.. in the device emulator opened Simulator->change sd card and chose add file .Then i gave db in the space for filename(such a file was currently not made) and then  a new db-sdcard.dmp file appeared.Here is where i created my database that is inside sdcard image file of blackberry emulator but cannot open or view the file on computer.Is there any means by which I can browse this sdcard file  and see my database inside?I wanted to add a lot of entries into the database and its difficult doing it through program.So if at all I cud access and view my db manually that would be  great . I have tried all sorts of db browsers

Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: try to use some DatabaseBrowser and you can see the database in database Browser I am Using SQLite Spy you can use others too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the [SQLite zip File](http://code.google.com/p/droidexplorer/downloads/detail?name=sqlitebrowser_200_b1_win.zip&can=2&q=)

and

extract it at any place and selects the **SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1 .exe** file and select the **fileName.db** file from the Emulator or simulator's SDCard then you can get the information.

You can see the data in the database;

Redirect the SDCard from simulator like......

[image: Click Add Directory and ReDirect the SdCard]

Comment: Yes i have done it all.... downloaded sqlite db browser and tried .but the thing is the sd card file made by emulator is stored in my drive as a .dmp file and my database is inside it.so cannot open it with db browser .any other way please.I've also tried winimage where i can open and browse through other dmp files but not this ..ppls help

Comment: Open the file SQLite Database Browser 2.0 b1 .exe after extracting. In that select "File-->open Database" option and redirect to ".db" file which is stored in your Drive by simulator. Then you can see all the tables in that database.

Comment: I did the same as u suggested ..still i cannot browse into the db file.When i try to select file->open database and click on file it says not an sqlite database(its obvious cz its a .dmp file my simulator makes).. but it works fine in simulator ..i can retrieve insert anything..

Comment: You have to give the file name as "filename.db" when you create a database file through code by 

uri=URI.create(dbLocation+"ManualRecords.db");
Here "ManualRecords.db" is my database file name. I think you understand. Because simulator should not give the extension(.dmp or anything) you must give the extension.

Comment: URI myURI = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/MyTestDatabase.db"); This is how my uri looks.And pls read my question once again cz i have updated it.If it is not the right way please help me out.Wantted to know how you guys make it thankyou

Comment: Simulator->change sd card-->choose "add Directory" not addFile. And redirect The SDCard. See the above posted answer I added the Image.

Comment: Thank you so much for the trouble!I created the database as u said ,inserted data and i can read data from database through my program.But my previous problem still exists .I cannot open MyTestDatabase.db file from SQLite database browser.It says not an sqlite 3 database.Pls help.

Comment: You can come into the chat room. Room name is: "Knowledge Sharing Center For Blackberry and Java". I always there for you.